# Compile Less files in Visual Studio 2013 for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less

I am new to **Less** and I am using **Visual Studio 2013** for Web for development. And i aware Visual Studio supports less files.

[image: Less Style Sheet]

I have added .less to my project and added small mix-ins..

While i build my project i didn't get corresponding css files.. Because of using Express edition i can't add Web Essential extension.

How do i compile my less files? Or is there is any other options to compile less files?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is now old but if you happen to still be looking for a solution then you will need to use an external application to compile your LESS files. There are a few out there but two I can recommend are...

- Koala - http://koala-app.com/
- SimpLESS - http://wearekiss.com/simpless

I have used both in conjunction with Visual Studio and can recommend either. They can compile on-the-fly every time you save your LESS file within VS and work pretty seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

look at : [Can Visual Studio 2013 generate CSS files from .less files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855426/can-visual-studio-2013-generate-css-files-from-less-files)